# How can I create a custom view for a survey list?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, survey-list

I have a survey, and need to be able to sort the responses based on one of the responses. For instance, Question 1 in the survey allows for a choice of A, B, or C. When I "view all results" in SP, I want to see a column for Question 1 in the view, as well as sort the records by the values contained...A, B, or C.

There does not appear to be a way to do this...

I'm using SP2010 Foundation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a [custom view using SharePoint Designer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-custom-list-view-using-sharepoint-designer-HA010379079.aspx).

This will allow you to build a custom CAML query that you can use to define your sorts, groups, and filters. You can use the [U2U CAML Query Builder](http://www.u2u.be/Tools/wincamlquerybuilder/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx) to help you compose the CAML.